# Parar un while con ENTER

Tags: c++

he estado intentando hacer un programa que requiere de un bucle While que vaya leyendo números y pare cuando se introduzca un Enter o retorno de carro, el tema es que no se realmente como se hace ya que el código que tengo no sale del bucle.

Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int valor_x{0};                         
    std::vector<double> vector_polinomio;
    std::string valor;
    while (std::cin >> valor) {
        if (valor == "\n") {
            break;
        }
        vector_polinomio.push_back(stoi(valor));
    }
    std::cout << "fin de bucle";
    return 0;
}
```

El programa leer un valor x y lo sustituye en el polinomio que se especifica mas abajo, trato de resolver el siguiente [problema](https://jutge.org/problems/P96767_en) de jutge

Answer (score 3):

Cuando se lee un texto de consola (`std::cin >> texto`) se asume que el espacio ( ) es el separador, si encuentra otro caracter (como el salto de línea) no lo consume y se queda en el búfer, así que puedes echar un vistazo (*peek* en inglés) si **después** de la lectura el siguiente elemento en el búfer es el salto de línea y finalizar:

```
while (std::cin >> valor) {
    vector_polinomio.push_back(stoi(valor));

    if (std::cin.peek() == '\n') {
        break;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdasMwDIWv46cQHazJxUr3c5WkeZJBcBynFXGs4NjZoOTZM2UulG3MGIyko@9IVuP4pIy053V9QKtMaDWUSJN3Wg6VuOdmrTy5Sgi0HgaJNs3EVSRbNEtDrv68HpcC/jsimXyb55FSthQaoyuIYT2SQUsDUnGTsT3acwRz7uOCRkP6XVJooapiKQOeIPkNOYxhutSNVD13EKZRmhWCtdjdMYdR6z7N4HSC/bvdR1jS8OI9eyaL4HubR1HwUJaw69idf6MJyujdRuzIQarITh5k8ASPM@R/1soY94Oz@W3vvCGc9sFZOBZiWddneIFXeBNf)</kbd>.

Pero parece que no quieres hacer esto, si tu intención es leer números hasta que no te faciliten ningún número más, puedes leer directamente sobre un entero y salir del bucle cuando falle la lectura:

```
int valor_x{0};                         
std::vector<double> vector_polinomio;

while (std::cin >> valor_x) {
    vector_polinomio.push_back(valor_x);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/dasMwDIWvracQHazJRUf3c5UEP0khOIq7mjpScOxsUPLsWbKujG1MN@KIo/NJ1Pc78oZf5/nOMfnUWqycDDFY02n4no2WogQN4DhiZxxnOVxArWo0XkL9ftlPJf5XoIbYFsU1pWolNd5qvMq6F@9YOiclgHo7OW8x@7STY9T6BshxAarfOw99Gk51Y@ic3XwlqAm@iCQpYlXh5rhkLY80ibzdrKCjBMxIeIhoUhS8H7H4c1G@EH/kbA@8Xfu4RgQbU2DclzDN8yM8wTO8AHwA)</kbd>.

Comment: Recuerda reiniciar el estado del stream, sino no podrás seguir leyendo. Con `cin.clear()`

Comment: @Mateo en el código original, no parece que Zake quiera seguir leyendo.

Comment: Solo lo menciono por si a caso.